# Cannot see the updated AdditionalProperties content in Adaptive Card in the chat

Tags: c#, adaptive-cards

Below is the code I'm trying:

```
var paths = new[] { ".", "Resources", "ListCard.json" };
var listCardJson = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(paths));

AdaptiveCard card = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(listCardJson).Card;
var properties = card.AdditionalProperties;

var obj = new AdaptiveTextBlock()
{
     Text = "Hello"
};

properties.Add("items", obj);

string jsonString = card.ToJson();

var listCardAttachment = new Attachment()
{
     ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.list",
     Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString),
}; 

return listCardAttachment;
```

Even though I can see that 'properties' is updated but I cannot see the new value in adaptive card in the chat.

Any solution?

Expecting to see the updated content in the card.